# States of "positronium" with chiral fermions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, chirality

When I combine positron and electron to form positronium, or generically two spin 1/2 particles, I have four possible spin combinations that arrange into a singlet and a triplet state, which in turn are the trivial and standard representations of SO(3).

Now, what does happen if one of the particles, or both, are chiral particles without their corresponding chiral partners? Imagine for the sake of discussion that you want to combine a neutrino and an electron, or two neutrinos, or a pair neutrino antineutrino. Are the combinations part of the SO(3) triplet, the singlet, or none of it?

Or instead neutrinos, think for instance mesons with one or two exotic chiral quarks.

Comment: Is this related to the question of the decay of positronium to neutrinos? I read that only the triplet state can decay.